# C++ CSS inliner

Tags: open-source, html, c++, css

Is there a simple open source CSS inliner like [Juice in Node.js](https://github.com/Automattic/juice), but in C++ (preferably Qt)?

Comment: I'm not into web development in C++, but - even if there isn't, it looks like Juice itself is not a lot of code. Perhaps it could just be ported to C++?